# Exact formula for the number of spanning trees of a rectangle

Tags: graph-theory, randomized-algorithms, matrices, tree

This blog talks about generating "twisty little mazes" using a computer an enumerating them.  The enumeration can be done using [Wilson's algorithm](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/11357811) to get the [UST](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/11363008), but I don't remember the formula for how many there.

http://strangelyconsistent.org/blog/youre-in-a-space-of-twisty-little-mazes-all-alike

[image]

In principle the [Matrix Tree Theorem](http://math.mit.edu/~levine/18.312/alg-comb-lecture-19.pdf) states the number of spanning trees of a graph is equal to the determinant of the Laplacian matrix of the graph.  Let $G= (E,V)$ be the graph and $A$ be the adjacency matrix, $D$ be the degree matrix, then $\Delta = D - A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda$, then:

$$ k(G) = \frac{1}{n} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \lambda_k $$

In the case of an $m \times n$ rectangle both $A$ and the eigenvalues should take a particularly simple form, which I can't find.

**What is the exact formula (and asymptotics) for the # of spanning trees of an $m \times n$ rectangle?**

[image]

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/c03ee31334ee89abad83) is a pretty example of Wilson's algorithm in action.

Comment: [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A116469) The exact formulas don't look easy to derive.

Comment: @PeterShor OEIS cites: Germain Kreweras, *Complexite et circuits Euleriens dans les sommes tensorielles de graphes*, J. Combin. Theory, B 24 (1978), 202-212.  He is the same objects as us right?

Comment: They cover a lot of different objects, including the *quadrillage planaire*, which is the $m \times n$ grid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to https://www.cse.ust.hk/~golin/pubs/ANALCO_05.pdf there is no closed-form formula known.

According to http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0004341v1.pdf the number is asymptotic (for $n$ and $m$ both large) to
$$\exp (z_{\mathrm{sq}}mn)$$
where
$$z_{\mathrm{sq}}=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)^2}\approx 1.16624$$
but I'm not sure whether this is a rigorous bound or the result of heuristic physics-based reasoning. The same paper also gives asymptotic formulas of similar type when $m$ is fixed to a small constant and $n$ is large.

Comment: There are precise asymptotic formulas for the number of spanning trees in a rectangle (and more general sequences of subgraphs described by rectilinear polygons) given here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0011042.pdf (specifically, corollary 2 and proposition 13)

Comment: Again, that's in a mathematical physics repository. Do they prove the asymptotic formulas rigorously or do they just use physics-like ansatz reasoning?

Comment: It was published in Acta Math 185 (2000) no. 2, 239-286.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of the m-by-n rectangle graph can be used to obtain an expression for the number of perfect matchings in such graphs.  See [the Wikipedia article on domino tilings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_tiling).

Comment: This is interesting, but can you elaborate how this adresses the question? Is there any kind of mapping between perfect matchings and spanning trees in this particular case?